# Redirect To Another Page and Hide/Show DIV using a Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two HTML files one is called index.html and the other one is called main.html. I have a button on index.html that when clicked it should redirect to main.html and show a hidden div there, using jquery. how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The button should be a `<a>` hyperlink that points to another html page.
Then, use JS to show the hidden div "`document.getElemenyById("myDiv").style.visibility="visible";`" when the page loads.

How to create a hyperlink:
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp

How to create an "onload" function:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible, granted that the two pages are on the same domain.

On `index.html`, add an event listener for `click` on the button. On click, set a value (say, 'show') to a key (say 'show-div') in `localStorage`.

On `main.html`, read the value from `localStorage` via `localStorage.getItem('show-div')`. If the key exists and the value is `show-div`, you can select the `div` and show it.

Here's an example on CodeSandbox:

[image: Edit crazy-dan-7r5np]

Answer (score 0):

You could add a query parameter to the link to main.html, such as:

```html
<a href="main.html?showdiv=true">Go to main</a>
```

Then on main.html you add a onload check to show that div if the query parameter is set:

```js
$(function() {
  if (location.search.includes('showdiv=true') {
    $('#divName').show();
  }
});
```